# Error-addresssanitizer-negative-size-param-size-(-4)

Tags: c++, string, substring

```
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    vector<char> v;

    int k=0;  
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        auto it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), s[i]);
        if(it==v.end()){
            v.push_back(s[i]);
        }else{
            if(v.size()>=k){
                k=v.size();
            }
            for(auto ti=v.begin(); (*ti)!=s[i]; ti++){
                v.erase(ti);
            }
            v.erase(it);
            v.push_back(s[i]);
        }

    }
    return v.size()>=k ? v.size():k;
}
};
```

Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

For input : "abcabcde" above code works fine but

For input : "abcabcdd" above code is giving the titled error.
Why am I getting the error?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `erase` may validate iterators, like `it` for instance.

Comment: Note that "works fine" is the most annoying manifestation of undefined behaviour. You can't conclude from a program's working fine that it's not broken.

Comment: @molbdnilo, it's `ti`, not `it`, that's used after invalidation.

Comment: @NathanOliver I found that error was due to inner for loop. If inner for loop isn't there, code isn't giving runtime error but also output is not desirable. I still couldn't resolve it.